# Slack Api: is it ever possible to update other user's messages?

Tags: slack, slack-api

We basically want to annotate certain messages (adding links) but it does not
seem to be possible using Slack API. Only way to modify is to give permission
to the user who posted that message and modify it as that user.
I can delete other users comments or file.

I have tried to update others messages using legacy token, app token's with
full permissions but no success.  I called Slack API as a owner or admin.

I used [chat.update](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update) Slack api method.

The response from the api call is an error "cant_update_message"

```
    "headers": {
        ....
    }, 
    "ok": false, 
    "error": "cant_update_message"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible to edit your own messages (assuming this is allows in your workspace), but never the messages of others. That is the same for all users including admins and owners. And its the same with the API method chat.update.

But there is a workaround: Your app can gather tokens from every user in your workspace and then use those token to impersonate each users allowing your app to change every message. This will require each user to install the app once. Your app then just needs to use the matching token to update each message.

Note that this workaround has some obvious drawbacks, e.g. giving your app access to all message and channels on the workspace and also requires some organizational effort to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not possible even if you are an admin, as slack [article](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202395258-Edit-or-delete-messages) say:

> <del>Mistkaes</del> Mistakes sometimes happen. Fortunately, members can edit and delete the messages they send in Slack (if allowed by Workspace Owners and Admins). Workspace Owners can also delete messages in public channels and private channels they've joined.

Slack Roles are the following:

1. Owner
2. Admin

### Permissions

## Owner and admin permissions:

1. Manage or @mention user groups
2. Set private channel retention
3. Delete a channel
4. Rename a channel *if you created the channel you can rename it.*
5. Make a public channel private
6. Create a private shared channel
7. Create a shared channel
8. Delete your own messages
9. Remove people from channels
10. Invite Guests to a public channel
11. Invite a Single-Channel Guest to a private channel
12. Delete other people's messages
13. Invite new Guest members
14. Deactivate a member's account
15. Promote a Workspace Admin

## Only Owners

1. Demote a Workspace Admin
2. Promote a Workspace Owner
3. Turn on Approved Apps

All of these permissions are allowed to them just, if you want to know all permissions, [read more](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201314026-Permissions-in-Slack)

Comment: Thanks. I thought so.  As an admin I can still delete others' files which is interesting.